# How to write VBA function activating different sheets?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm writing a VBA function using an input that determines the sheet containing other inputs.

With different curvename, the function should refer to data in different sheets. My code is as below:

```
Public Function DFrate(mtmdate As Date, pmtdate As Date, curvename As String, colno As Integer) As Double

Dim yf As Double
Dim noday As Integer
Dim lastrow As Integer
Dim rate As Range
Dim tenor As Range
Dim DFinv As Double
Dim DFinv1 As Double
Dim DFinv2 As Double

noday = pmtdate - mtmdate
yf = noday / 360
MsgBox noday

ThisWorkbook.Sheets("HS_" & curvename).Activate
lastrow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
Set rate = ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(102, 3 + colno), Cells(lastrow, 3 + colno))
Set tenor = ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(102, 2), Cells(lastrow, 2))

If (noday <= tenor(1, 1)) Then

     DFinv1 = (1 + rate(1, 1) / 100) ^ yf
     DFinv2 = (1 + rate(2, 1) / 100) ^ yf
     DFinv = DFinv1 + (noday - tenor(1, 1)) * (DFinv2 - DFinv1) / (tenor(2, 1) - tenor(1, 1))
     MsgBox DFinv

End If
For k = 1 To lastrow

     If (noday > tenor(k, 1) And noday <= tenor(k + 1, 1)) Then
            DFinv1 = (1 + rate(k, 1) / 100) ^ (tenor(k, 1) / 360)
            DFinv2 = (1 + rate(k + 1, 1) / 100) ^ (tenor(k + 1, 1) / 360)
            DFinv = DFinv1 + (noday - tenor(k, 1)) * (DFinv2 - DFinv1) / (tenor(k + 1, 1) - tenor(k, 1))

            Exit For
     End If
    Next k
DFrate = DFinv

End Function
```

I got the error #NAME?
Even the message box "Msgbox noday" does not work.

Can someone please let me know what should be changed in my code? Thanks!

Comment: Put `Option Explicit` at the top of the code sheet and try again.

Comment: Have you stepped through your code using the debugger to identify which line gives the error? Also, are you sure that `curvename` (passed in as a parameter) is valid i.e. `("HS_" & curvename)` is a valid sheet name?

Comment: @user10829321 I tried, but it did work

Comment: @AlexP Yep, I checked that the curve name is valid. I wonder why even the message box does not give a result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I:

- put the code below (which is slightly different to yours) in a regular module (not `Thisworkbook` or any of the `Sheet` modules),
- create a worksheet named `"HS_O"`,
- put `5` in cell `B102` of worksheet `"HS_O"`, put `3` in cell `D102` of worksheet `"HS_O"`
- and put `=DFrate(TODAY(),TODAY(),"O",1)` in any cell of any worksheet within `Thisworkbook`

I get a return value of `1`. I think it works for me (and should work for you too in theory).

```
Option Explicit

Public Function DFrate(mtmdate As Date, pmtdate As Date, curvename As String, colno As Long) As Double

    Dim yf As Double
    Dim noday As Long
    Dim lastrow As Long
    Dim rate As Range
    Dim tenor As Range
    Dim DFinv As Double
    Dim DFinv1 As Double
    Dim DFinv2 As Double
    Dim k As Long

    noday = pmtdate - mtmdate
    yf = noday / 360

    ' Maybe have a defensive check/guard
    ' or some return particular return value if sheet doesn't exist
    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("HS_" & curvename)
        lastrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
        Set rate = .Range(.Cells(102, 3 + colno), .Cells(lastrow, 3 + colno))
        Set tenor = .Range(.Cells(102, 2), .Cells(lastrow, 2))
    End With

    If (noday <= tenor(1, 1)) Then
         DFinv1 = (1 + rate(1, 1) / 100) ^ yf
         DFinv2 = (1 + rate(2, 1) / 100) ^ yf
         DFinv = DFinv1 + (noday - tenor(1, 1)) * (DFinv2 - DFinv1) / (tenor(2, 1) - tenor(1, 1))
         MsgBox DFinv
    End If

    For k = 1 To lastrow
         If (noday > tenor(k, 1) And noday <= tenor(k + 1, 1)) Then
            DFinv1 = (1 + rate(k, 1) / 100) ^ (tenor(k, 1) / 360)
            DFinv2 = (1 + rate(k + 1, 1) / 100) ^ (tenor(k + 1, 1) / 360)
            DFinv = DFinv1 + (noday - tenor(k, 1)) * (DFinv2 - DFinv1) / (tenor(k + 1, 1) - tenor(k, 1))

            Exit For
         End If
        Next k
    DFrate = DFinv

End Function
```

I don't deal with calling UDFs from the worksheet much. Maybe merely calling the function activates the sheet the function is on, and not the `"HS_" & curvename` worksheet. I don't know for sure. Either way, we can use a `With` statement.